# How to send pictures using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, imessage

I made a script that sends messages to people. I also want to be able to send pictures through this script.

```
on run
    tell application "Messages"
        set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
        set targetBuddy to buddy "18008888888" of targetService

        repeat 3 times
            send "/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/photo.png" to 
targetBuddy
        end repeat

    end tell
end run
```

Putting the directory of the photo in quotations makes the message sent be a string, and taking away the quotes results in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `file` reference. Try

```
send POSIX file "/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/photo.png" to targetBuddy
```

or

```
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "photo.png"

tell application "Messages"
    set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
    set targetBuddy to buddy "18008888888" of targetService

    repeat 3 times
        send file filePath to targetBuddy
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Possibly this used to work? I get a failed delivery after a while

Comment: @Jens Bodal - Works for me. Just tried it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was missing the permission in `settings => security/privacy => privacy => accessibility` for the `imessage` script

Comment: @hepcat72 when you do this does it show up on other devices or just the device you sent from? When I use this it "sends" the file but it doesn't actually get sent to my phone

Comment: What I'm seeing might be related to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429586/applescript-messages-app-monterey-problem

Comment: It shows up on all devices, but that may be due to my iCloud settings/preferences. If you want to try my version, I posted it here: https://gist.github.com/hepcat72/6b7abd9000e8b108ecdb76e12da1257e Just use the `--attachment` option. And... I'm running Monterey.

Comment: And incidentally, my script defaults to SMS and only uses iMessage as a backup (because currently, SMS messages can get through without a data connection).